# Scrolling up flatlist when textinput of an item is focussed, leads to scroll down immediately to the item which was focussed already

Tags: react-native

Focussing of textinput of last item in flatlist appears keyboard but immeadiately keyboard disappears. In order to solve this,using a property removeClippedSubviews={false} of flatlist fixes this issue but it causes to another issue i.e,

Whenever an item is focussed aleardy in flatlist and tries to scrolling up the items, items are scrolling upto pagination limit and then right after items are scrolling down to the item that is focussed already of flatlist(focussed item appears on top of flatlist interms of visibility).Since it is not allowing scrolling up further.

Is there any property or workaround to fix these two issues? Do anyone got this issue? please provide solution if there is any?

1. Flatlist without "removeClippedSubviews={false}" property, scrolling is fine but for focussing of textinput of last item of flatlist causes keyboard appears and disappears.(keyboard should not disappear)

2.Using SafeAreaView, keeping flatlist in scrollview are also not working.

```
<FlatList style={styles.flatListSection}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
data={this.state.serverData}
renderItem={this.iterateFlatListItem}
ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => this.seperatorComponent() }
ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
onEndReached={()=>this.handleLoadMore()}
keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
extraData={this.props}
ref={ (r) => this.refFlatlist=r }/>
```

1. Scrolling up should work without scroll down automatically when textinput is focussed
2. Focus of text input of last item of flatlist, keyboard should not diappear once it appears unleass we dismiss it manually